# How can i parse an itm.txt file?

Tags: rust, embedded, embedded-linux, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I am new to embedded and Rust programming. I am working on sensor and I am able to get the readings of the sensor.

The problem:
The data is in the `itm.txt` file which includes headers and a variable-length payload, [Data in itm.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMdSo.png). When I am getting the readings of the sensor I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zDC9.png).
Can someone please help me to parse this data, I am finding no way in Rust to parse this data.

This is the code I am using to get the file content.

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read, BufReader};
fn decode<R: io::Read>(mut r: R) -> io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut output = vec![];
    loop {
        let mut len = 0u8;
        r.read_exact(std::slice::from_mut(&mut len))?;
        let len = 1 << (len - 1);
        let mut buf = vec![0; len];
        let res = r.read_exact(&mut buf);
        if buf == b"\0" {
            break;
        }
        output.extend(buf);
    }
    Ok(output)
}
fn main() {
    //let data = "{ x: 579, y: -197 , z: -485 }\0";
    let mut file = File::open("/tmp/itm.txt").expect("No such file is present at this location");
    let mut buf_reader = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut buf_reader).expect("error");
    let content = std::str::from_utf8(&buf_reader).unwrap();
    println!("raw str: {:?}", content);
    println!("raw hex: {:x?}", content.as_bytes());
    let decoded = decode(content.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    let s = std::str::from_utf8(&decoded).expect("Failed");
    println!("decoded str: {:?}", s);
}
```

The error I am getting now

```
raw str: "\u{2}Un\u{3}scal\u{3}edMe\u{3}asur\u{3}emen\u{1}t\u{1} \u{2}{ \u{1}x\u{2}: \u{2}31\u{1}3\u{1},\u{1} \n\n"
raw hex: [2, 55, 6e, 3, 73, 63, 61, 6c, 3, 65, 64, 4d, 65, 3, 61, 73, 75, 72, 3, 65, 6d, 65, 6e, 1, 74, 1, 20, 2, 7b, 20, 1, 78, 2, 3a, 20, 2, 33, 31, 1, 33, 1, 2c, 1, 20, a, a]
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: UnexpectedEof, message: "failed to fill whole buffer" }', src/main.rs:51:46
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

This is the [link](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/06-hello-world/index.html) to itm thing.

Comment: The [`itm` crate](https://docs.rs/itm/) can be used to parse the ITM dataframes. The documentation doesn't contain a lot of guide-level information, so it will be a bit hard to get started, but you can probably look at the source code of the included `itmdump` tool to get an idea how to use the library.

Comment: After using the **itm::decoder::from_slice** my readings of Vec<u8> are converted in Packets. Updated the code above.

Comment: As I mentioned before, you should take a look at the `itmdump` source code. Specifically, [this part of the code unwraps the payload](https://github.com/rust-embedded/itm/blob/v0.3.1/src/bin/itmdump.rs#L96-L102), which appears to be what you are trying to do. (Note that I don't have the slightest clue what all of this is about – just pointing at some code that appears to do what you are trying to do.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach can you please look the above updated code and the error I am facing while readings my itm.txt data. Reading data variable is fine with the function but while readings from file it shows this.